# Liferay Portlet which will tell if the liferay server is up and running

Tags: liferay, portlet

My company is running many applications and one of them is liferay portal. The liferay portlet consists of many plugins(portlets, themes, hooks).

Now I have to develop an application, which will show the status of liferay-server. whether it is up and running? and what all portlets are deployed in it.

We are using Liferay with tomcat server

is there any way in liferay to determine what all custom-portlets are deployed in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cat get a list of all portlets:

```
PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets();
```

And for watching the state of liferay-server is useful to develop a small portlet with web service interface.

Comment: can u please expand on what you mean by "develop a small portlet with web-service interface", Correct me if I am wrong, you mean to say we should use service-builder interface and create a service which will tell if the server is up and running?

Comment: yes, you can use e.g. json web service, see http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/json-web-services